# Time in heat transformation

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

How can I calculate the time it takes for two objects with certain temperature and capacity to exchange their heat and reach the equilibrium temperature? What constant or … should I have?
Thanks.

Comment: Another good idea for an exam question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the temperature as the function of time you have to solve the Heat equation viz. $$\frac{ \partial u}{ \partial t} - a \frac{ \partial^2 u}{ \partial x^2}=0$$

visite [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation)
for more information.